# copy from drop down to textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I've got 2 drop down lists. First is department, second is based on first that shows employeers of that department. Now I just need to copy selected value from second drop down list into the textbox. Some onchange functions? Or how does it work? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you done any searching for client-side (javascript) and how to interact with controls?

Comment: I'm using PHP. I just have html block of 2 drop down lists and a textbox where i need to copy data.

Comment: I've searched for javascript, but I cudn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information you supplied, here's how you would do it... basically.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/My7D5/)

```
<select id="mydropbox" onchange="copyValue()">
<option>
...
</option>
</select>

function copyValue(){

   var dropboxvalue = document.getElementById('mydropbox').value;
   document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = dropboxvalue;

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to copy value to `<span>` and not into the textbox? or into some label?

Comment: Use document.getElementById('spanId').innerHTML= dropboxvalue; if you want to copy dropboxvalue to a span element.